# Block all sites except one

Tags: network, imac

I have been assigned the task of installing an iMac that is only allowed to use one specific site, and block access to all other IP addresses. The iMac will be on display at a resort so guests can fill in a questionnaire hosted on the resort website.

My questions are:

1. How do I block all outgoing traffic except for traffic to IP `xx.xx.xx.xx`?
2. Is it possible to set up a user account that is only allowed to use Safari? Or set it up so that a password is required to exit fullscreen mode? Or is there a better solution to set up a web page in fullscreen mode on an iMac and prevent the user from doing other tasks?

Comment: Search for Kiosk mode - it seems at least Opera can do that

Answer (score 2):

Check out Parental Control. This allows to restrict applications to run as well as web sites to visit.

---

Alternatively you can use `ipfw` to restrict IP/Internet access:

```
 sudo ipfw -f flush
 sudo ipfw add allow tcp from me to xx.xx.xx.xx
 sudo ipfw add allow ip from me to xx.xx.xx.xx
 sudo ipfw add deny tcp from me to any
 sudo ipfw add deny ip from me to any
```

To disable just run `sudo ipfw flush` again

Comment: Your syntax needs a little work. "ip" is actually "all" (they are interchangeable), so you don't need the "tcp" rules. Additionally, it's wise to set in/out flags and use "any" instead of "me". Lastly, you have them reversed, the rule should be: `add deny ip from 0.0.0.0 to any in`. It seems counterintuitive that rules should be inbound but that's how blocking works.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out [Plainview](http://barbariangroup.com/software/plainview). This is designed for kiosk style presentations, it's not a hardened security app. But it seems like it might work for your application.